# Passing a raw SQL query to query builder on Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Is there a way to initialize laravel's query builder with a raw query? Or at least to pass a full raw SQL query in an existing instance? Something like this:

```
$rawSQL = "select * from table ...";
$builder = DB::query($rawSQL); // returns a query builder instance
$builder->where(...); // like a normal ->where method in query builder
```

I have tried DB::select, but it returns an array, not a query builder instance that can be updated by more queries.

Comment: Yes you can: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#raw-expressions

Comment: @Justinas  I will try that, but it seems to only allow fragments of raw queries, but not whole queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Builder::fromSub()`](https://laravel.com/api/8.x//Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_fromSub):

```php
$rawSQL = "select * from table ...";
$builder = DB::query();
$builder->fromSub($rawSQL);
$builder->where(...); // like a normal ->where method in query builder
```

Comment: Using your example: $builder-->toSql() returns "select * from select * from table ...". The query is malformed. Although you gave me an idea. If I can turn the query into "select * from (select * from table) as t" how slow can the whole query be?

Comment: I don't think, that would make the query significantly slower but if that can be avoided, that would be even better.

Comment: What you're attempting to do is possible via `$query->fromSub($rawSQL, 'sub')`

Comment: Unfortunately, the Builder doesn't seem to have a way to parse a whole query.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Builder::fromRaw](https://laravel.com/api/8.x//Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_fromRaw), but note the syntax: it doesn't contain any 'select * from ...' - this would be added automatically:

```
DB::query()->fromRaw('users')->get();
```